# how to find out whether the its view or partial view from controller context?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to find out whether i am getting error in View or Partial View. Or in general how do we find out whether the its view or partial view from controller context.

Answer (score 1):

Get the stack trace and try to process from it where the error is.  If you need to do this in code you could probably make use of the StackTrace class or the StackTrace from the exception if you are catching one.

you can process the stack trace like this:

```
var stackTrace = new StackTrace(true);
        foreach (var r in stackTrace.GetFrames())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Filename: {0} Method: {1} Line: {2} Column: {3}  ",
                r.GetFileName(),r.GetMethod(), r.GetFileLineNumber(),
                r.GetFileColumnNumber() );
        }
```

and the fileName property you could see whether it matches your partial class file.

Comment: hey its not required for debugging purpose. I need to know to handle errors in effective way.

Answer (score 1):

Best thing you can do is add a bool to ViewBag.isPartial from the controller.

You always want to use holders for such information and never discover them on the view side if you want to be truly in the MVC spirit.

Also, usually it's not a good idea to use the same view both as partial and as a main view. This means that you haven't thought out well the role it plays.

Most common use for such a similar setting would be to change the layout, ie: for mobile, web, etc..